# TypeScript: Error when using string enum inside another enum and comparing it with strings

Tags: typescript, enums

I have string enum and I want to use it inside another enum. But then if I want to compare enum item with a string I get an error.
The last line of this code gives error.
Why?
And how to make it work?

```
enum UserRoles {
  admin = "Admin",
  user = "User"
}

// this compiles and prints 'true'
console.log(UserRoles.admin === "Admin");

enum OrgRoles {
  admin = UserRoles.admin,
  user = UserRoles.user
}

// this doesn't compile
// error: This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 
//        'OrgRoles' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)
console.log(OrgRoles.admin === "Admin");
```

Comment: I don't see any error [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAqgzsATgJQPYBthygbwFBRQCGAJhAJYhQC8UA5AIJmV0A0BUYCiN98SbPAF88eAPRioAFwAW5bAGNUEAA7lM2IiBJQViSlOx0piMMDp4lIOBmAA6dKgDmACn4pbcO6QpVq-+iZfOgBKAG5RUEgoAHlEJzQNXA4fSl53RKxvZhB2Qi4kdO5MrwLEdhFxSVl5KBJULBBjKCVVdWAqqCREVEQALigAFTlFZRUifRsqIhUVYAnsKVQoACNgThADUClyVBAidFXgBSIC6Rl1qQBPObhOwgfCOjiEzzpibXo4E0ond5kiAA3dYgZaoYGIdAzOyGFwAJgAzAA2ADsIUsexsmAczhcLxK2V8NACjByoQiQA)

Comment: Probably it depends on some 'strict' compilation flags?

Comment: I made everything related to `strict` `true` [here](https://tsplay.dev/wEpY4W)

Comment: Could you please try to use typescript version 4.1.5?

Comment: It compiles cleanly under 5.x, but flags an error under 4.x

Comment: Yes, I see an error on TS 4.x, so how you would like to approach this problem? The obvious decision is to upgrade the version or you can just do `OrgRoles.admin.toString()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed in TypeScript 5.

See Github issue: [String enums from string constants #43902](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43902)

Fixed in TS5 by [Enum unification and improvements #50528](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/50528)